# A fatal exception 0E occured at 0028:xxxxxx in VxD IOS(01)

Tags: windows, boot, bsod, windows-98

I get a blue screen of death in my windows 98 machine every time I boot it. I can't reach to my desktop. The error is like this:

```
A fatal exception 0E occured at 0028:C003CC2F in VxD IOS(01) + 0000156B

This was called from 0028:C0082E60 in VxD VKD(01) + 000001D0
```

I have to then give it a three finger salute to restart the system. There is no other way to shut down the system at this point except pressing the CPU power button.

What could be the problem?

My windows **system.ini** is:

```
[boot]
oemfonts.fon=vgaoem.fon
shell=Explorer.exe
system.drv=system.drv
drivers=mmsystem.dll power.drv
user.exe=user.exe
gdi.exe=gdi.exe
sound.drv=mmsound.drv
dibeng.drv=dibeng.dll
comm.drv=comm.drv
mouse.drv=mouse.drv
keyboard.drv=keyboard.drv
*DisplayFallback=0
fonts.fon=vgasys.fon
fixedfon.fon=vgafix.fon
386Grabber=vgafull.3gr
display.drv=pnpdrvr.drv

[keyboard]
keyboard.dll=
oemansi.bin=
subtype=
type=4

[boot.description]
system.drv=Standard PC
mouse.drv=Standard mouse
keyboard.typ=Standard 101/102-Key or Microsoft Natural Keyboard
aspect=100,96,96
display.drv=Standard PCI Graphics Adapter (VGA)

[386Enh]
;device=tddebug.386
;device=D:\TC\TASM\BIN\WINDPMI.386
ebios=*ebios
woafont=dosapp.fon
mouse=*vmouse, msmouse.vxd
device=*dynapage
device=*vcd
device=*vpd
device=*int13
keyboard=*vkd
display=*vdd,*vflatd
ConservativeSwapfileUsage=0
Paging=on

[NonWindowsApp]
TTInitialSizes=4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 18 20 22

[power.drv]

[drivers]
wavemapper=*.drv
MSACM.imaadpcm=*.acm
;msvideo.STV680=STV680sg.drv
midi=mmsystem.dll
wave=mmsystem.dll
MSACM.msadpcm=*.acm

[iccvid.drv]

[mciseq.drv]

[mci]
cdaudio=mcicda.drv
sequencer=mciseq.drv
waveaudio=mciwave.drv
avivideo=mciavi.drv
videodisc=mcipionr.drv
vcr=mcivisca.drv
MPEGVideo=mciqtz.drv
MPEGVideo2=mciqtz.drv

[vcache]

[MSNP32]


[DISPLAY]
BusThrottle=1

[network]
SSID=1438661605

[vicax]
msacm711=74603
msacm811=148933
msacm911=42405

[Sessew]
VideoManufacturer=Standard VGA
VideoBoard=Standard Display Adapter (VGA)
MouseType=0
VidType=0
Mono=0
Ddraw=1

[drivers32]
msacm.lhacm=lhacm.acm
VIDC.IV50=ir50_32.dll
msacm.iac2=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM\IAC25_32.AX
VIDC.YUY2=msyuv.dll
VIDC.UYVY=msyuv.dll
VIDC.YVYU=msyuv.dll
msacm.msaudio1=msaud32.acm
msacm.vorbis=vorbis.acm
msacm.l3acm=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM\L3CODECA.ACM
msacm.sl_anet=sl_anet.acm
VIDC.TSCC=tsccvid.dll
VIDC.IV41=IR41_32.AX
vidc.mpg4=mpg4c32.dll
vidc.mp43=mpg4c32.dll
msacm.voxacm160=vct3216.acm
MSACM.msadpcm=msadp32.acm

[TTFontDimenCache]
0 4=2 4
0 5=3 5
0 6=4 6
0 7=4 7
0 8=5 8
0 9=5 9
0 10=6 10
0 11=7 11
0 12=7 12
0 13=8 13
0 14=8 14
0 15=9 15
0 16=10 16
0 18=11 18
0 20=12 20
0 22=13 22
```

Comment: In Device Manager, can you see the I/O ports?  Offhand, I have a Win7 system, not a Win98 system.  Hopefully these directions will be useful anyway.  On the _V_iew menu, I can choose "resources by t_y_pe".  See if any of those I/O port ranges are numbers near 0028:C003CC2F or 0028:C003CC2F or the values you see added.  That may help to identify problematic driver behavior (which can happen, even with a good driver, when that driver has to interact with bad hardware).  So that may narrow the driver or hardware causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would try following the [Troubleshooting Windows 98 Startup Problems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188867/en-us) guide from Microsoft.

It will have you try to boot into Safe Mode first:

> **Start Windows 98 in Safe Mode**
>
> If Windows 98 does not start normally,
>   try to start it in Safe mode. Starting
>   Windows 98 in Safe mode bypasses the
>   current real-mode configuration and
>   loads a minimal protected-mode
>   configuration, disabling Windows 98
>   device drivers and using the standard
>   VGA display adapter. To start Windows
>   98 in Safe mode, restart your
>   computer, press and hold down the CTRL
>   key until the Windows 98 Startup menu
>   appears, and then choose Safe Mode. If
>   you can start in Safe mode, see the
>   steps in the "Windows 98 Starts in
>   Safe Mode" section of this article.
>
> If Windows 98 does not start in Safe
>   mode, see the "Windows 98 Does Not
>   Start in Safe Mode" section of this
>   article.

The article will take you step-by-step through different files to help you try to figure out where the problem is coming from.

Comment: //@ When you have a SCSI printer powered on, online, and connected to a configured SCSI port @// - I don't have a printer connected to the system, btw. And, isn't your solution applied only to Windows 95? Can I install the updated IOS.VXD in my win98 system? thanx in advance!

Comment: You're right - it looks like that's just Windows 95. I took that part out - have you tried their troubleshooting steps I linked?

Answer (score 0):

Just seen this question bumped by Community - If you haven't found a solution yet, I just want to add a bit of general advice.

My advice would simply be that this machine is now over 12 years old, if you have not installed anything recently, the most likely cause of the problem is simply hardware failure.

On machines this old, the first thing I would check is the hard drive, and possibly swap it if you have a spare. After this, it could be anything - motherboard, add-on card, memory or other. There just is not really an easy way to find out.